# On the matrix $I-\frac{1}{n}\cdot J$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a fixed positive integer $n \ge 3$, let $A$ be the $n \times n$ matrix defined as $A = I - \frac 1 n J$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $J$ is the $n \times n$ matrix with all entries equal to $1$. Which of the following statements is NOT true?

1. $A^k = A$ for every positive integer $k$.
2. $\operatorname{Trace}(A) = n - 1$.
3. $\operatorname{Rank}(A) + \operatorname{Rank}(I - A) = n$
4. $A$ is invertible.

Matrix theory, Linear Algebra, Rank, Inverse

Comment: Can you please share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried? Questions in which a problem is merely copy-pasted into the post are frequently given a rather poor reception; so please indicate your efforts on the problem.

Comment: I didn't find anything special in the matrix A.

Comment: Have you at least tried part (1)? Just take $n = 3$, write down a couple matrices, and try multiplying them. Same with part (2). If you don't have any ideas for the general case, try doing a couple of small ones.

Comment: Option 2 is TRUE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's most of it:

For any $n \times n$ matrix $B$, $B^2 = B$ implies $B^k = B$ for all positve integers $k$, seen by a very easy induction:  assuming $B^m = B$, we have $B^{m + 1} = B^2 = B$ whence, taking $B^2 = B$ as the base case as well, we have $B^k = B$ for all $k$.  Applying this to our matrix $A$, we see that

$A^2 = I^2 - (2 / n) J + (1 / n^2) J^2, \tag{1}$

and since

$J^2 = nJ$, (1) becomes

$A^2 = I - (2/n)J + (1 / n^2) nJ = I - (2 / n)J + (1 /n)J = I - (1 / n)J = A, \tag{2}$

so that

$A^k =A \tag{3}$

follows immediately.  Thus we have established item (1.).

For item (2.), it is easy to see that the diagonal entries of $A$ are each $1 - (1 / n)$, whence

$\text{Tr}(A) = n(1- (1 / n)) = n -1. \tag{3}$

So item (2.) is true.

Turning now to item (4.), let $v = (1, 1, . . . , 1)^T$ be the vector all of whose entries are $1$.  Then

$Av = (I - (1/n)J)v = v - (1/n)Jv, \tag{4}$

and since

$Jv = nv, \tag{5}$

equation (4) becomes

$Av = v - v = 0, \tag{6}$

showing that $0 \ne v \in \ker A$; thus $A$ is not invertible, so item (4.) is false.

As for item (3.), note that

$I - A = (1 / n)J, \tag{7}$

every row and column of which is $(1 / n)v$ for $v$ as defined above.  Thus $\text{rank} (I - A) =1$.  And that's as far as I got at the moment.  To finish this off, we need to show that $\text{rank} A = n - 1$.  Or not.   I'm still working on it but Seasonal Obligations beckon me at present, and I'm sure most of my readers understand that tardiness in such matters is often not well recieved.  So perhaps someone else can pick up the ball; in any event, I'll edit this post as soon as I've figured out this last piece of the puzzle, which hopefully will be in fairly short order.  Or, this being the Season of Sharing, we can share in the completion of the answer, that is, showing $\text{rank} A = n -1$.  Or not.

***Note Added in Edit, Christmas Day 2013, 10:21 AM PST:***  OK, let's finish this thing off right now:  we still need to show that $\text{rank} A = n -1$.  To this end, note that by equation (6) above, and/or the falsity of item (4.), there exists the nonzero vector $v$ with $Av = 0$; from these things we may immediately conclude that $\text{rank} A \le n-1$.  This suggests we examine sets of $n -1$ columns of $A$ for possible linear dependence/independence.  Let $v_j$, $1 \le j \le n$, be the columns of $A$.  Consider the set $\{ v_1, v_2, . . . . v_{n -1} \}$ consisting of the first $n - 1$ columns.  This set is linearly dependent if and only if there exist $n  - 1$ scalars $b_1, b_2, . . . , b_{n -1}$, not all zero, such that

$\sum_1^{n - 1} b_j v_j = 0. \tag{8}$

Setting $b_n = 0$, define the vector

$b = (b_1, b_2, . . . , b_{n - 1}, b_n)^T = (b_1, b_2, . . ., b_{n - 1}, 0)^T; \tag{9}$

it is then easy to see that (8) is equivalent to

$Ab = 0, \tag{10}$

or using the definition of $A = I - (1 / n)J$,

$(I - (1 / n)J)b = 0, \tag{11}$

or

$b = (1 / n)Jb. \tag{12}$

Writing out (12) in compoment form, we see that for $1 \le j \le n- 1$ we have

$b_j = (1 / n) \sum_1^{n - 1} b_k, \tag{13}$

whereas the final equation for $b_n$ is

$0 = b_n = (1 / n) \sum_1^{n - 1} b_k; \tag{14}$

if we now insert (14) into (13), we see that

$b_j = 0 \tag{15}$

for *all* $j$, showing the $v_j$, $1 \le j \le n - 1$, must be linearly independent.  Thus we arrive at the conclusion $\text{rank} A = n - 1$; with what we have done above, this establishes that item (3.) is in fact true.  And that just about does it, doesn't it?

***End of Note Added in Edit.***

Hope this helps.  Yuletide Greetings,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thank you very much. You are a true expert @Robert Lewis http://math.stackexchange.com/users/67071/robert-lewis

Comment: @ user113500:  And you are most welcome; happy I could help out.  I think I've got the last part nearly done as well, and should be posting it soon.    So stay tuned!  Meanwhile, have a Merry Christmas!

Comment: @ user113500:  OK, I posted the last part if you want to check it out!